# TS - Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am getting this weird error from TypeScript:

> "Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword."

**What?**

[image]

The constructor function, just looks like:

```
function Suman(obj: ISumanInputs): void {

  const projectRoot = _suman.projectRoot;

  // via options
  this.fileName = obj.fileName;
  this.slicedFileName = obj.fileName.slice(projectRoot.length);
  this.networkLog = obj.networkLog;
  this.outputPath = obj.outputPath;
  this.timestamp = obj.timestamp;
  this.sumanId = ++sumanId;

  // initialize
  this.allDescribeBlocks = [];
  this.describeOnlyIsTriggered = false;
  this.deps = null;
  this.numHooksSkipped = 0;
  this.numHooksStubbed = 0;
  this.numBlocksSkipped = 0;

}
```

I have no idea what the problem is. I tried adding and removing the return type (void) but that did nothing.

Comment: `new (function Class() {})()` throws a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `ISumanInputs` does not include one or more of the properties that you're including in your call *or* that you haven't properly fulfilled the `IsumanInputs` interface.

In the extra property case you should get one "extra" error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'anExtraProp' does not exist in type 'ISumanInputs'

In the missing property case you will get a different "extra" error:

> Property 'timestamp' is missing in type '{ fileName: string; networkLog: string; outputPath: string; }'.

Interestingly enough, if you move the definition of the argument out of line the *extra property* case no longer fails:

```
const data = {
  fileName: "abc",
  networkLog: "",
  outputPath: "",
  timestamp: "",
  anExtraProperty: true
};

new Suman(data);
```

Answer (score 7):

As Sean pointed out, this is a less obvious consequence of type mismatch in arguments.

In case a deeper reason interests you: when arguments of a function don't typecheck, `tsc` infers return type to be a special type `never` (overriding `void` you specified). And `new` with such a function will cause `TS2350 Only a void function can...`.

This snippet can trigger TS2350 without incorrect arguments.

```
function Ctor(): never {
    throw "never return";
}

const v = new Ctor();
```